# Delphi: Can I start short apps from a service?

Tags: delphi, service, subprocess, rights

I created a scheduler. It was threaded first, but because of memory leaks and separatable tasks I changed to subprocesses.

The service starts the subprocesses by N minutes or in determined time.
I finished with all thing, but I'm not sure now that service can start an application or not?

I want to use this as processfarm - as PostgreSQL in Windows.
But I want to avoid that virusscanners "eat" (block) my subprocesses, and I need all rights to run them.

Can I do thins under any OS from WinXP to Win7?

What I need to pre-think, what with I need to calculate, etc.?

Thanks for your every answer:
  dd

Comment: Why are you rewriting Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: Because I do many things in it: check a main DataBase, register the subprocesses. If the Master service died or stopped, but subprocess not, I register it also alive.
And the subprocesses are running only ONCE. If they are alive, I cannot start them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, services can start other programs.

Comment: Just note that if the launched program is a visual app, it needs to be run inside a user's interactive session in order to be visible onscreen.  Use CreateProcessAsUser() instead of CreateProcess() for that.

Comment: And how to I start a process to it begin as child process of the Master (the Scheduler) service?

Comment: Use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx). Or, as the comment above already suggested, [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429.aspx). I'm sure that question has already been answered here on Stack Overflow.